# What is a changeset in Git?

Tags: git

What is changeset in Git? I keep hearing this term said, but cannot seem to find the answer online, and wikipedia is very vague. Is it if you commit 5 files at once via a git repository and type git log and see a single commit for that 5 files, that entire change is called a changeset?

```
commit 01304a265f5d8f9bfd6eb64d3390846adc61db75
i.e.:Author: Some guy <someguy@hotmail.com>
Date:   Thu Jul 28 18:28:07 2016 -0400

First commit
```

This entire thing would be a changeset?

Comment: There is no such concept in git. If you see someone using it, ask *them* what they mean by it.

Comment: Actually, it is a concept, but more for version control in general. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changeset And yeah it is the same as a commit.

Comment: @gran_profaci if you write that as an answer, I will accept that as the accepted answer

Comment: Please don't minus this question. I myself have met this "changeset" terminology in one of IDEs (PHPStorm, if I get it correcty). But IDE's "changeset" did just what I needed so I let it be. Now, I went to Bitbucket's API documentation and simply coldn;t find there any methods for "commits". Don't get me wrong, I "came to VCS" on Git's shoulders, so, I haven't heard about changesets before. Besides, maybe there's a slight difference? Maybe not.. It's quite hard to google something, when everyone around knows this and no one asks ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As was mentioned by the other folks as well, a [changeset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changeset) is essentially one indivisible change. Indivisible simply means that a changeset is one single value in the stack of changes that are being made on a codebase. For example, if you look at a commit, you can check what individual files were modified, what was the previous state of the codebase and after, which would make it adhere to what a changeset is.

Comment: It's worth adding that Git does not *store* changesets.  Instead, Git *computes* a changeset, given a commit, by comparing that commit to its parent commit.  This works for most commits, but not for merges (which have at least *two* parents, so you must pick one first) and not for root commits (which have no parents).

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.  I found this page after submitting a PR for documentation, I thought it would be a decent first "real" PR.  I was met with this message from the build bot:  "⚠️ No Changeset found.  Merging this PR will not cause a version bump for any packages. If these changes should not result in a new version, you're good to go. If these changes should result in a version bump, you need to add a changeset. When changesets are added to this PR, you'll see the packages that this PR includes changesets for and the associated semver types."  Not sure what it means, docs not updated